# trying to add a file to ~/.ssh but it is not a directory

Tags: ssh, terminal

I'm trying to create a ~/.ssh/config file but when run "touch ~/.ssh/config" file in the terminal, it says that " ~/.ssh/config" is not a directory. It seems that my ~/.ssh is a file and not a folder so is it safe to assume that I can delete the existing file and create the directory?

Comment: You have to create the directory first. `.ssh` probably doesn't exist at all yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can first check if your `.ssh` is existing at all:

```
file ~/.ssh
```

If this returns an error message like "...(No such file or directory)" you can just create that folder with

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
```

Then you can continue with your `touch` command.

Comment: if your .ssh exists, please add a comment so I can add more details.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would recommend to you is checking if your folders exist (like ~ and .ssh).

If they do not exist, you can use mkdir to create them.

Another thing I would recommend is doing "touch" and "mkdir" from inside the folders (if you can access them) as it would be a lot less difficult to write the command to create your files and folders.